# I want to create this navbar, with its respective animation

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, flutter-animation, dart-pub

How do I add this type of animation to my navbar, which when pressed shrinks the size of the icons and a text appears from the top, displaying the name of the respective page?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qauj.gif

Edit: The text on the top of the icon appears only, when you keep on pressing the bar items and disappear when you release the pressing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [stylish_bottom_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/stylish_bottom_bar) to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am pretty new to flutter so getting used to it right now and I don't have much experience designing a navbar this accurately, so I was looking for some definitive answers.

Comment: Just use this package and example is also provided there, you can have a look at it.

Comment: Okay! I will look into it.